# How to upgrade servlet 2.5 to 3.0 on Resin 3.1 pro

Tags: java, servlets, resin

I try to make spring project with STS and resin 3.1.
but it has problem. Ex: " java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus() " 
"getStatus()" is required servlet 3.0 but resin 3.1 supports servlet 2.5. so How can i upgrade ?

Comment: You have to upgrade to Resin 4.0.1. See [here](http://www.caucho.com/resin-4.0/changes/resin-4.0.1.xtp#Resin4.0.1Overview)

Comment: Is there any way other than resin version upgrading?